# l2circuit-control-passthrough on Juniper MX Boxes

Tags: juniper-mx, metro-ethernet

I need to do some Y.1564 Measurements between 2 Cisco Boxes that are connected by a L2 Martini Circuit on a Juniper MPLS Fabric based on MX480s and MX204s.

I think the default behavior of Juniper is to handle Ethernet OAM as Control Traffic and not to tunnel this on a L2circuit by default.

I found this article, and it says that this feature was implemented for PTXes. I can agree that neither on the MX480s nor on the MX204s this configuration feature is available.
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/mpls/topics/ref/statement/forwarding-options-l2circuit-control-passthrough.html

Is there any possibility to enforce the behavior (Tunnel Ethernet OAM on a L2Circuit) in MXes? Baybe ba an alternate Configuration parameter.

I consulted the feature navigator in Pathfinder and couldn't see any clues here.